# Why am I getting this error with this Java code?

Tags: java

This is the beginning of the file. It's named correctly, the classes are all defined, but it's giving me an error.

> error: '{' expected; (on the first line of my given code)

```
public class ClassRoster extends Student extends Belt
{
```

What's going on?

Comment: You can't inherit from multiple classes in Java (you have two extend clauses).

Comment: Multiple inheritance is not allowed in java If you want to do so use interfaces.

Comment: which upcoming version of java allowing multiple inheritance?

Comment: @ay89 it is a basic principle of java do disallow multiple inheritance

Answer (score 3):

You can't have "extends Student extends Belt". You can't extend 2 classes as multiple inheritance is not supported (and it would be comma separated if you could, like it is with implements).

What you could do is have:

```
public class ClassRoster extends Student
```

And your Student class extends Belt

```
public class Student extends Belt
```

Answer (score 3):

No multiple inheritance in java.

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't extend more than one class. There is no multiple inheritance in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot extends two classes in Java.
Either

```
public class ClassRoster extends Student{
```

or

```
public class ClassRoster extends Belt {
```

However if you want both then go for interface based Implementation

Answer (score 0):

Java does not support extending multiple classes so only one `extends` is allowed

Answer (score 0):

In java you are not allowed to extend more than one java class.

Answer (score 0):

Given that Java only supports single-inheritance, the second `extends` is causing the problem.

That is, you can only extend one class from one other.

Answer (score 0):

Java does not support multiple inheritance. You have 2 `extends` statements.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the extend keyword twice, because Java doesn't support multiple inheritance. If Belt is an interface, then you must write:

```
public class ClassRoster extends Student implements Belt {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to break the basic principles of java.

The inheritance feature of Java does not allow multiple inheritance. This means you can not "extend" two Classes at the same time, but if you can "implement" more than two "intefaces".

Please follow [this link](http://javapapers.com/core-java/why-multiple-inheritance-is-not-supported-in-java/) to get more information on it.

Hope i am able to make to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have misconception about the `extends` and `implements` keyword

You can extends only one class i.e. called superclass